# not able to send mail using python

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

I'm using the following method to send mail from Python using SMTP.
I have tried many times to run this code which is right but it always shows me the same error is there anyone who can help me in this.

```
import smtplib

TO = 'xxx@gmail.com'

SUBJECT = 'TEST MAIL'
TEXT = 'Here is a message from python.'

gms = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
gm = 'www'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()`enter code here`
server.starttls()
server.login(gms, gm)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                    'From: %s' % gms,
                    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                    '', TEXT])

try:
    server.sendmail(gms, [TO], BODY)
    print('email sent')
finally:
    print('Error sending mail')
server.quit()
```

And the errors are:-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:/projects/Intern/Mail/Maill.py", line 10, in <module>
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
      File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
      File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
        self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
      File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
        self.source_address)
      File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "C:\Users\KD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Have u enabled access to less secure apps for your google account?

Comment: @Paandittya Can't be. The gmail server would respond with that error code if that was the problem. This error seems to be a firewall issue.

Comment: @Paandittya yes I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a local issue with your firewall or ISP, which is probably blocking outgoing SMTP connections. There is no other reason why smtp.gmail.com should timeout - it should always be online. Even if the credentials were invalid, you usually get a smart error code from the gmail server.

Check your antivirus software or firewall. Or try using a Web/HTTP API for sending email, instead of SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall and network settings and make sure that you have port `587` open!  The error states that you can't even open a connection w/ `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: If you are running mac or linux, does anything show up when you run the following command?`netstat -atun | grep :587`